# geotools - how to `CRS.decode` without loading hsql?

Tags: geotools

When I want get CRS, I saw sample code using `CRS.decode("EPSG:4326")`. But I seems like I should load `hsql` for that.

But I don't want to load `hsql` just to load CRS.

What would be alternative? 
Any pointer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile(group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-epsg-wkt', version: '19.2')
```

After adding dependancy for `gt-epsg-wkt:19.2`, `CRS.decode("EPSG:4326")` works.